# How to make an angularjs directive aware of whether or not it is visible on the page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some custom directives, which control custom validations.

These directives may be hidden by an ngShow or ngHide directive, on its own element or an ancestor element.

**How can I make my directive aware of whether or not it is hidden**? (so that when another controller asks about its contents it won't report validation errors)

I guess it's possible to have a method on the directive's controller that checks whether the directive's element, or any of its ancestor elements have an ng-show/hide attribute set with an expression that evaluates within its own scope so as to hide it... But this would require an undesirable quantity of logic and dom access (slow), and so I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: Why not check the variable that you are using to show and hide the element? Directives can still access scope!

Comment: @drew_w because it's not a variable per se, it's an angular expression which could be arbitrarily complex, and because it could be an ancestor element which is actually hidden, which lives in a scope that the directive in question doesn't have direct access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer an approach where the directive does not need to know what on scope may be showing or hiding its ancestor, and check the element directly to determine if its visible.

```
if (element.offsetWidth === 0 || element.offsetHeight === 0) return false;
```

The above script will return false if the element is hidden for any reason, wether it be `ng-show` on the element itself, on an ancestor or css or otherwise.

Comment: is there any reason to check `offsetWidth OR offsetHeight`, as opposed to a conjunction of the two or just one of them?

Comment: Yes. For example an element with a positive height but zero width is hidden, and and element with positive width but zero height is also hidden.

Answer (score 2):

if your directive is declared somewhat like this:

```
<mydir ng-show='showThisDir'></mydir>
```

then it is linked to a scope variable like so:

```
$scope.showThisDir = true;
```

then add data to the scope of your directive, so it should be something like this:

```
.directive('mydir', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        someData: '=info',
        isShown: '='
      },
      template: 'some html'
    };
```

});

and add it in your declaration like so:

```
<mydir ng-show='showThisDir' is-shown='showThisDir'></mydir>
```

now your directive is aware of whether it is shown

another way could be:

```
.directive('mydir', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var display = element.css('display'); 
        // whether it is displayed, but this would get more complicated 
        // as you need to set watchers when you changed data and
        // recalculate the display value
    },
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        someData: '=info',
      },
      template: 'some html'
    };
```

});

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would work if an ancestor of the directive is hidden.

Comment: this is only for the element itself, if you want to check against ancestors, you need add the logic for it

Comment: you can start with element.children().attr('ng-hide'); or element.children().css('display'); ... well actually you'd have to probably loop through the children and check each one